# Visualforce: Draw Grid Functionality with panelGrid

Tags: visualforce, panelgrid

Is there the ability to draw a grid so I could create a VF page similar to an excel sheet in look and feel?

Could panelGrid support this? Please see the image below to see my end goal.

[image]

Thanks again for your help, yall experts!

Comment: do you need to be able to enter formulas and have a ribbon bar to format like in excel -- or do you just want a table with borders and shading?  If the latter, panelGrid will work fine combined with CSS

Comment: @crop1645 The latter, the goal is to have users enter inputs into this table. My end users are very attached to their Excel forms, so they really want the "Excel" look to continue. Could you please provide an example of panelGrid with CSS?

Comment: I suggest you look in the VF documentation for examples - panelGrid in turn becomes an HTML table and there are countless examples in the Internet on how to style HTML tables; someone else may chime in with an answer but always best to show that you tried something as that is the community spirit

Comment: @crop1645 Digging into the VF documentation now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create Excel like Visualforce very easily, Here are some references

- [Making a Spreadsheets with Apex and Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_A_Spreadsheet_On_Force.com)
- [Visualforce Table Grid](https://github.com/Up2Go/visualforce-table-grid)
- [Yet Another Pageblock table Enhancer component](http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2013/11/pageblocktableenhanceradv-yet-another.html)